# Error when trying to install valgrind on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

Having trouble tracking down a solution to the following problem. I am running Ubuntu 10.04.

```
~$ apt-get install valgrind
   Reading package lists... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean.... etc
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     valgrind: Depends: libc6-dbg but it is not going to be installed
   E: Broken packages
~$ apt-get install libc6-dbg
   ...stuff...
   lic6-dbg: Depends libc6 (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10 is to be installed
   E: Broken packages
~$
```

Any suggestions are appreciated...!

Comment: @sputnick Checked gcc compatability; downloaded Valgrind separately and tried to manually install (after it was installed it output an error related to the above); searched the error; tried Synaptic; searched '2.11.1-0ubuntu7.x'... now, I am a beginner, so perhaps the solution was close, but I have been working on it for several days now to no avail.

Comment: @d0rmLife Looks like you are mixing two different versions of Ubuntu. Don't do that.

Comment: @jordanm Indeed, it is not a pure Ubuntu build. I am trying to become comfortable with Backtrack 5 r3 KDE 64-bit in preparation for an internship. Do you have any advice regarding my problem? Do you imagine any other *bigger* problems down the road? Is there a way around them?

Comment: @d0rmLife have you tried with `aptitude install valgrind`   ???

Comment: @RahulPatil I just entered the command... says it will downgrade libc-bin, libc-dev-bin, libc6, libc6-dev, libc6-i386 and upstart. Score is 80. Is there a potential for adverse results from downgrading these packages?

Comment: @d0rmLife don't know, but try first `aptitude update && aptitude upgrade && aptitude install valgrind`

Comment: @d0rmlife yes, remove all non-bt5 repos from your sources.

Comment: @RahulPatil Many things were installed/upgraded with that command, but the same option to downgrade came up for Valgrind...!

Comment: @jordanm Not sure if you're serious? As I said I am a beginner! I will have to learn quickly I suppose. Do you advise against the downgrading that `aptitude install valgrind` suggests?

Comment: Very serious. Never mix distros or versions of distros. Even with careful pinning you are likely to end up with an entire system of whatever contains higher version, and probably quite a few broken ones. The upgrade you ran in the earlier comment likely gave you a system that would no longer be considered BT5.

Comment: @jordanm I am surprised 1) because that command seemed to mostly update the applications that BT is known for purveying, and 2) because I believe the only source that is enabled for aptitude update etc is from backtrack.com/etc. Sorry to bother you with more questions, but I really do appreciate the help... Surely BT allows updates, especially of the aforementioned app's... is there a better way to do it? Also, and more importantly, is there a way to determine the status of my current build... i.e. what I should do from here?

Comment: @jordanm I guess I am confused how I have mixed distributions after merely updating/upgrading aptitude on BT5? Sorry again, just trying to learn.